# Use a custom C++ library in a Swift iOS project

Tags: ios

I have a C++ lib as a separate project that I'm trying to use in a Swift iOS app.

The approach I'm pursuing right now is:

1. Compile the lib into .dylib. This happens outside of Xcode.
2. In Xcode, add the lib to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.
3. Add the (C compatible) header to Bridging-Header.h.
4. Now, build succeeds but it crashes on simulator (something like ".dylib not found"), because the .dylib is not added to the app package.

Unfortunately I couldn't add the .dylib to "Embedded Binaries". I guess it must be somehow packaged into a framework (no idea how)?

How to make this work? Is including the sources into the project a better approach?

Comment: If it says `.dylib` not found, I believe it may have happened due to not adding the path of your library in `Header Search Paths` in `Build Settings`. Please let me know if it's some other error.

Comment: @KrishnaCA the header is found correctly at compile time. It crashes on the simulator, because it can't find the .dylib library.

Comment: I believe it should also crash on the device due to same reason then. For packaging the c++ library into a framework, you can create a cocoa touch framework right and add the c++ library to it. Then, you can use Objective C++ to create an interface for your project to interact with the framework. Given that you can define public and private headers in the `Cocoa Touch Framework`, I believe it may satisfy your requirements